# how to test if CComBSTR is empty

Tags: string, com, visual-studio-2005, atl, bstr

How to test if a `CComBSTR` is an empty string? (with no 'text' value, can be `""` or can be `null`)

my ideas:

1. test if `CComBSTR::ByteLength()` returns 0
2. test if `CComBSTR::GetStreamSize()` returns 0
3. test if `CComBSTR::m_str` is NULL
4. test if `CComBSTR::Length()` returns 0

which one is correct approach? if none of them is, then what is correct approach?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4) Test length 0 it's fast as it's stored

Comment: Actually it results in `SysStringLength()` being called which is not the fastest thing in the world.

Comment: Why's it slow? They're length prepended.

Answer (score 0):

3) test if CComBSTR::m_str is NULL

If you check the source code of CComBSTR there's several operators you can use to do this test:

```
bool CComBSTR::operator!() const throw()
bool CComBSTR::operator!=(int nNull) const throw()
bool CComBSTR::operator==(int nNull) const throw()
operator CComBSTR::BSTR() const throw()
```

For example:

```
CComBSTR value;
if (!value) { /* NULL */ } else { /* not NULL */ }
if (value != NULL) { /* not NULL */ } else { /* NULL */ }
if (value == NULL) { /* NULL */ } else { /* not NULL */ }
if ((BSTR) value) { /* not NULL */ } else { /* NULL */ }
```